# ASP.NET App performance & Memory leaks

Tags: asp.net, performance, memory-leaks

We have an ASP.NET 4.0 web app, with more than 200 pages. It has a public site and a cms.
We have installed this app in almost 30 domains in the same server, so each of those domains has the app installed.

The server memory (private working set) grows slowly but it grows. The server has 8 GB RAM, but at the enb of the day, somedays, we get an OutOfMemory message although we are recycling the AppPool every morning.

It has to have memory leaks, but we don't know how to locate those leaks. We have tried to dispose every element we can...

We need some help on this. 
Is there a company that offers these kind of services, I mean to check apps and fix memory leaks?

Thanks.-

After some researching I have found a lot of lines like this:

Label xLabel = (Label)FormView.FindControl("xLabel")

with no dispose. Don't you think that can generate a huge leak? Wouldn't be better:

using (Label xLabel = (Label)FormView.FindControl("xLabel"))
{ Actions }

Thanks

Comment: It might even harm if you disposed `xLabel`, since `FormView` may work with it later on during the ASP.NET page lifecycle. As it appears to be placed within another control, disposing should work.

Answer (score 0):

New Relic offer such a service: https://newrelic.com/ there is a free trial and they offer pretty good analytics on your application.

Or to perform it yourself you could check out this article from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658248.aspx

---

'Disclaimer - customer, not employee.

Comment: thanks, I have edit my mesage because I have found some code I think could be really bad..

Answer (score 0):

There is something obviously wrong if you get Out of Memory, end of every day after a recycle the previous day. I guess you should be able to figure out looking at code or using VS.NET memory profilers if you have the right edition of it.

You could also look at professional profiling tools such as [Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), which is a good one that I found helpful on many occasions.

If you do not have an environment where profilers could be run, you could get a memory dump (with DebugDiag or even with Task Manager) and examine (using windbg) objects in memory, which could lead you to bad code. If there is someone who is hands on with WinDbg , this is rather a quicker option (because memory issues are show stoppers) than using profiling tools or digging into code if the code base is huge.

By the way, the sample code you have put in - such references should be cleaned up automatically by GC when the container is cleaned up. If the container (View) that holds the label itself is not properly disposed, then it can be an issue. The issue generally would be with other objects (large ones) that are being referenced and not cleaned up properly.